# How do you use a dependency .dll when there can only be one within the release directory?

Tags: c#, mongodb, dll

Sorry if the title isn't too clear!

**Context:**

I'm building a modification for a game I didn't create - 7 Days To Die. I'm new to the world of C# so apologies if this is a  very basic question.

**My problem:**

- I'm referencing the Mongodb C# driver in my project
- There's no issues upon compiling
- The game enforces the use of a single .dll within each 'mod' directory, I don't know where to correctly place my Mongodb .dll files so that I don't get thrown a 'Could not load file or assembly' error.

**What I've tried:**

- Creating a sub-directory for the dependencies within the mod directory
- Loading the Mongodb .dll files as-if they were mods
- Merging the files together into a single .dll

I'm yet to find a way that allows me to create my mod with these dependencies. I'd really appreciate some guidance here because I've done a day or so of searching to no luck. Thanks!

Comment: What happened in the first try? if you added the dll in its own sub directory, what is the problem with that? what error do you see?

Comment: It continued throwing the 'Could not load file or assembly' error at me. Might I add that this error is being thrown from the game logs, not within my build process.

Comment: although you have all dll files? where each file has its own sub folder?

Comment: Indeed, a single .dll within the mod folder root, and then a sub-directory for the dependencies. All of which are inside.

Comment: If Mongo lib requires to have more than one file in one folder, but you have limitation to one file, then the first thing I can think of is to register the dll files to the GAC (if having a .dll in folder under folder under folder... doesn't work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after all that time I think I've finally got it. For anyone that's currently stuck with the same problem:

Place your dependencies in the /managed/ directory of your dedicated server data root.